# nginx not starting inside Docker

Tags: bash, nginx, docker, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.4
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y nginx

ADD configurations/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD configurations/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
RUN ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf

RUN chown -Rf www-data.www-data /var/www/

ADD scripts/start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 755 /start.sh

EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/start.sh"]
```

The start.sh script:

```
cat scripts/start.sh 

service nginx start
echo "test" > /tmp/test
```

When I log to the container:

```
docker exec --interactive --tty my_container bash
```

neither the test file exists nor nginx is running. There are no errors on the nginx log.

Comment: It is probably that Docker expects your app to start running and never return, as in a foreground process.  If your start script returns then Docker exits.  So try the solution linked above.

Comment: You can use official image like an example https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/19799fa644461ed6c5ea07c0bc0ea0cc277c2d77/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile

Comment: What happens when you login using `exec` to your container and try to run `/bin/bash /start.sh`. It will give you the exact failures that might be occurring when it tries to run start.sh at entrypoint.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to run the process in the foreground instead of as a service.

Remove the start.sh file and change the CMD to:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

You can get a better idea reading the official nginx dockerfile: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/jessie/Dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
RUN /etc/init.d/nginx start
```